# Update angularjs value in controller based on DOM value that gets updated from the 3rd party library later

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Third party library loads js and make modifications of DOM.
It happens much much (unpredictable time - in 1, 10, 30 seconds) later than angularjs controller gets activated.

how to update

```
myCtrl.myvalue = document.querySelector('abd[def="ghi"]').content
```

with the latest value after `'abd[def="ghi"]'` element gets updated per third party library described above.

If that simplifies things, with that library, the DOM element gets updated only once.

Comment: Can you share some code? is that 3rd lib has an AngularJs adapter?

Comment: No, it has no AngularJS adapter. Nothing related to AngularJS.

Comment: Ok, can you share the lib & some more code? sounds like you need to create such adapter for this lib

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the code.